# Davicom Semiconductor, Inc. 21x4x DEC-Tulip not detected by Wireshark but IP operational

Tags: pci

Recently flipped to Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dell 4300 (Intel). Getting IP address and no issues (ping/surf) but Wireshark unable to detect eth0 interface. I see references in forums to blacklist tulip but looks like I am running dmfe. Not sure if the blacklist is required and where to go from here. Maybe Driver update? Got a little lost looking in that area.

Some h/w details below (IP/MAC/HOSTNAME removed)

Linux xxxxxx 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 17:34:21 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

network-admin (HOSTS TAB) does not list eth0, only loopback and bunch of IPv6 interfaces

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxxxxxxx  
          inet addr:192.168.x.xx  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxxxxxxxxx 64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36662 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:42115779 (42.1 MB)  TX bytes:3056435 (3.0 MB)
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0xe800 

lspci
02:09.0 Ethernet controller: Davicom Semiconductor, Inc. 21x4x DEC-Tulip compatible 10/100 Ethernet (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Device 4554:434e
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Memory at fe1ffc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fe200000 [disabled] [size=256K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: dmfe
    Kernel modules: dmfe

hwinfo --netcard
20: PCI 209.0: 0200 Ethernet controller                         
  [Created at pci.318]
  Unique ID: rBUF.0NgK5ZS9c0D
  Parent ID: 6NW+.siohrLUzzI4
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:02:09.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:02:09.0
  Hardware Class: network
  Model: "Davicom 21x4x DEC-Tulip compatible 10/100 Ethernet"
  Vendor: pci 0x1282 "Davicom Semiconductor, Inc."
  Device: pci 0x9102 "21x4x DEC-Tulip compatible 10/100 Ethernet"
  SubVendor: pci 0x4554 
  SubDevice: pci 0x434e 
  Revision: 0x31
  Driver: "dmfe"
  Driver Modules: "dmfe"
  Device File: eth0
  I/O Ports: 0xe800-0xe8ff (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xfe1ffc00-0xfe1ffcff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xfe200000-0xfe23ffff (ro,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 18 (61379 events)
  HW Address: 00:08:a1:01:35:70
  Link detected: yes
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001282d00009102sv00004554sd0000434Ebc02sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: dmfe is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe dmfe"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #11 (PCI bridge)
```

Answer (score 1):

I sourced the issue , PEBKAC , need to run Wireshark as root or alternatively as described here: `/usr/share/doc/wireshark-common/README.Debian`